# Figures much clearer in the internal PDF-Viewer

Tags: floats, pdf, viewers

I have a problem:

In my thesis I added some figures via:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure.png}
    \caption{blablabla}
    \label{Abb.1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

My problem is, that the internal PDF-Viewer (I use TexMaker V4.1.1 under Debian Wheezy x64) displays the figures much, much clearer than any external PDF-Viewer.. But I am opening the same (!) file.

The following link shows a screenshot. On the left side one can see the internal Viewer from TexMaker and on the right side my external.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AiMy.png

Thank you in advance!

Edit: What I have tried so far:

- As suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7185/how-to-make-the-pdf-output-of-better-print-quality?rq=1) I installed cm-super. But it didn't change anything. (This might not have been the right approach.. I mean the fonts look fine, it's just the figures. But I wanted to try it anyway.)
- Also [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120260/making-low-quality-pdf-files-clearer) didn't bring any changes...

Comment: Your pictures are bitmaps (.png) and so fonts doesn't matter. Recreate your pictures in a better quality (eg. as vector graphics).

Comment: It seems that Texmaker's viewers doesn't do antialiasing, while the external viewer does.

Comment: Thank you both!
Thank you Ulrike, your workaround worked fine for me!

And thanks egreg for pointing out the reason for the differences between those two appearances.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was simply about a difference between viewer renderings.