# Why do my PDF figures in PDFTeX look bad in print?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, printing, matplotlib

I am using several figures created using Matplotlib in a LaTeX document that I compile with PDFTeX.  When I print the compiled PDF, I find that the figure quality is not optimum on some printers, although text gets printed well. Here is an example:

[image: Printed PDF with poor quality figure]

The axis labels in that graph have a much poorer print quality than the figure name and caption. Is there a way I can improve the print quality of the Figure? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Does the following question help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7185/how-to-make-the-pdf-output-of-better-print-quality

Comment: Can you add a minimum *compiling* example (.tex + a small figure) so that we can reproduce the PDF ourselves?

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions. I seem to have found a workaround for this problem: the figures get printed with good resolution if I use Acrobat Reader instead of Preview on my Mac.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment