# Matplotlib PDF figures blurry when printed

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, matplotlib

I'm creating my figures with Matplotlib. They are in the standard pdf output format of Matplotlib and I include them with `\includegraphics{figure.pdf}`. In my python scripts I activated the `usetex` flag to have all figure labels typeset with latex. The generated tex document looks great.

Unfortunately, when printed, the figure labels are a little blurry as if the figure is first rasterised before sent to the printer.

[image]

The label "Strecke in µm" is not as sharp and crisp as the figure caption underneath. It's harder to tell from the picture than from the document laying right in front of me but I hope someone had the problem before and can help me out. Using the `\includegraphics` flag `interpolate` made it a little better but not as if there was no difference.

Is there a way to make the labels being as sharp as the surrounding text in the printed version? (pdf document is fine!) Could it be a problem with the printer?

Thanks a lot,
Cheers

Comment: In the (closed) related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314888/why-do-my-pdf-figures-in-pdftex-look-bad-in-print it was suggested that printing from a different viewer resulted in improvements.